# How can I make a symfony 4 command to be registered only in dev environment and disabled in prod?

Tags: command, symfony4, autowired, production-environment, disable

In my `App` I have a helper class `App\Command\GenerateFixturesCommand` that provides a command named `my-nice-project:generate-fixtures`.

This command consumes a service of my own project named `App\Services\CatalogFixtureGenerator` that generates 1000 random PDF documents for testing while developing the app.

To do so, this service uses the `joshtronic\LoremIpsum` class which is required in composer only in `dev`. [LoremIpsum is a third-party library.](https://github.com/joshtronic/php-loremipsum) I require it under composer's `require-dev`.

So the injection is:

1. I run my `GenerateFixturesCommand`.
2. Before that, the system transparently locates my `CatalogFixtureGenerator` and to inject it into the command.
3. Before that, the system transparently locates the `LoremIpsum` third party service to inject it into my fixture generator service.

All is autowired.

When I deploy to `prod` and do `composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader` of course the `LoremIpsum` class is not installed.

But when I clear the cache with `APP_ENV=prod php bin/console cache:clear` the framework finds the command and cannot inject the autowired dependencies.

```
[WARNING] Some commands could not be registered:
In CatalogsFixtureGenerator.php line 26:
Class 'joshtronic\LoremIpsum' not found
```

This `my-nice-project:generate-fixtures` command is never going to be used in the production server.

## Question

How can I "disable" the command in `prod`?

I mean: How can I tell the framework that the class `GenerateFixturesCommand` should not be loaded nor its autowired dependencies, and neither of them should be autowired in `prod`?

Comment: Untested, so this is just a thought. How about excluding `App\Command\GenerateFixturesCommand` from autowiring in your `services.yaml` file, but then including it in one of the `/dev/` config files?

Comment: May I exclude just a single class from autowiring?

Comment: I've not tried, but if not then you can put this one file into its own folder, then you can exclude this folder? Not as elegant, but it should work.

Comment: You can definetely exclude a specific service from autowiring by manually defining it and setting: `autowiring: false` but I think you may run in the same problem: your service itself won't be able to register with an unknown class argument. If so, you can try a compiler pass at kernel level to check env and remove the unwanted command service https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html

Answer (score 6):

Use the `isEnabled()` method in Command.
For example

```php
    public function isEnabled(): bool
    {
        // disable on prod
        if ($this->appKernel->getEnvironment() === 'prod') {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my last project, I need some commands to work only in dev environment. You use `getenv` function to achieve this:

```php
# src/Command/SomeCommand.php
...

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if (getenv("APP_ENV") !== "dev") {
        exit('This command should work only "dev" environment.');
    }
}
```

This will do the trick.

Code fun :)

Comment: I don't get the point with your solution. I think this does not solve what I ask. What I ask is not about discovering dev/prod inside the instantiated command. It's about not instantiating it at all, because the mere fact of instantiation requires the Dependency Injection chain to be ready. Could you, please, clarify how do you prevent instantiation  of the command from the Symfony Kernel or tell the kernel to not resolve the dependency injection for that command?

Answer (score 0):

The solution @gusDeCooL suggests doesn't work with lazy-loaded commands (at least not for me).

I ended up implementing the `isEnabled()` method anyway, but then I added a guard in `execute()`:

```php
<?php


namespace App\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Attribute\AsCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;

#[AsCommand(
    name: 'command:name',
    description: 'Some description',
)]
class CommandName extends Command
{
    public function isEnabled(): bool
    {
        return 'dev' === getenv('APP_ENV');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);

        if (!$this->isEnabled()) {
            $io->error('This command is only available in `dev` environment.');
            exit(1);
        }

        // the rest
    }
}
```